# how to use cdecl callback with pinvoke

Tags: c#, callback, pinvoke

I have a c library that has cdecl callbacks. How can I use these from c#.

Everything seems to say that they must be stdcall callbacks

to be clear:

```
delegate int del();
[dllimport("mylib.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int funcwithcallback(del foo);
```

where del must be called cdecl-wise

Comment: Are you trying to create a `Cdecl` callback in C# (i.e. a `Cdecl` function that unmanaged code can call), or are you trying to call an unmanaged (i.e. native C) `Cdecl` function from C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at this. The functionality has been around since 1.1 so it should cover whatever .NET version you are using. You just have to specify the CallingConvention.

[CallingConvention Documenation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6f9ef9d(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also look at this article on Code Project:

[Using the _CDECL calling convention in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cdeclcallback.aspx)

EDIT: Also, Here is a example from FreeImage.NET.

```
static FreeImage_OutputMessageFunction freeimage_outputmessage_proc = NULL;
DLL_API void DLL_CALLCONV
FreeImage_SetOutputMessage(FreeImage_OutputMessageFunction omf);
```

Then on the C# side, simply:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void FreeImage_OutputMessageFunction(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT
format, string msg);

[DllImport(dllName, EntryPoint="FreeImage_SetOutputMessage")]
public static extern void SetOutputMessage(FreeImage_OutputMessageFunction
omf);
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Compile with .NET 2.0, use 2005 compiler!!
2. Reverse the argument direction.

It works due to some safeguard code added by the 2005 compiler.

EDIT: Don't try this if you can possibly make a shim in native code.

Comment: There's more to `cdecl` than just the parameter order. `StdCall` expects the called function to clean up the stack, whereas `Cdecl` expects the caller to clean up the stack. Mixing the calling conventions will result in a stack imbalance.

Comment: @Jim: I know that. I discovered by accident the 2005 compiler contains fixup logic when marshalling. When I upgraded to the 2010 compiler it didn't work and I had one heck of a time figuring out why.